# Read a CSV file one line at a time and then within the loop parse each line into the Class fields and then store that Class Object into an array

Tags: java, arrays, file

I want to read a CSV file one line at a time and then within the loop parse each line into the Class fields and then store that Class Object into an array.

The java class looks like this.

class Main{

```
String a;
String b;

public String getA() {
    return a;
}
public void setA(String a) {
    this.a = a;
}
public String getB() {
    return b;
}
public void setB(String b) {
    this.b = b;
}

public Main(String a, String b) {
    super();
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
```

}

I have written this code.

```
Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\souravpal\\Documents\\Bandicam\\a.csv"));
        Main us = new USCrimeClass();
        StringBuilder sb = new Main();
        while(inFile1.hasNext()) {
            String line = inFile1.nextLine();
            String elements[] = line.split(",");
            us.setProcess(elements[0],elements[1],elements[5],elements[9]);
            System.out.println(us.toString());
        }
```

Comment: Why do you think your approach is wrong?

Comment: @Kevin Anderson, can you please help to solve this

Comment: You already had what seemed like a perfectly reasonable solution.  What was wrong with it?

Comment: actually, I have to sort each field. How can I implement that in my code sir?

Comment: Sort each field?  I assume you mean "sort the `Main` objects (once they've been created) by the A and/or B fields", yes?

Comment: I want to add each column of the CSV file to class fields. Now I want to find the max values of the column. so should I sort the field?

Comment: All well and good.  And actually, you can find the max value in a column (or many columns) without sorting.  But the first task is to get the file read and parsed into `Main` objects.   And, as I said before, it looked like you had a perfectly good way of doing that already, But you thought there was something wrong with it.  I'l write you an answer, but I think it will end up looking exactly like the solution you already had...

Comment: can we chat on LinkedIn, please? https://www.linkedin.com/in/souravpal01/

Answer (score 0):

"CSV" could mean a lot of different things, but I'll assume your CSV file is fairly simple:

```
Avalue1, Bvalue1
Avalue2, Bvalue2
Avalue3, Bvalue3
  etc.
```

Here's how you can parse that into a `List` of `Main` objects:

```
List<Main> loadCSV(String filename) {
    List<Main> result = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileInputStream(filename)))
    {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] cols = line.split("\\s*,\\s*");
            result.add(new Main(cols[0], cols[1]);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: After saving the values in the fields of the class, how can I get the values for a particular column?

Comment: The imported instances of **Main** are contained within the returned List Interface from the **loadCSV()** method Kevin has so kindly provided. To use the loadCSV() method and import instances of Main Objects from file would be: `List<Main> list = losdCSV("C:\\YourFolder\\YourDataFile.txt");`. To view the imported instances of Main Objects you can iterate through the List: `for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) { Main instance = list.get(i); System.out.println("Object #" + (i+1) + ": --> Value A: " + instance.getA() + "  |  Value B: " + instance.getB()); }`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a library (which can deal with commas within a quoted field), such as
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html

```
File infile = new File("/path/to/myfile.csv");
CSVParser parser = CSVParser.parse(infile, CSVFormat.RFC4180);
for (CSVRecord record : parser) {
    String a = record.get("A");
    String b = record.get("B");
    ...
}
```